# Error when checking if a comma separated list is empty (blank)

Tags: arrays, batch-file, string-comparison

I get a comma separated list with values of a field from database. This list is sometimes blank. I need to check if the list is blank, then do something. If the list is not blank, then take another action.

Problem is that I am getting an error while checking if the list is blank. Here is the code. Please note that I have simulated at the beginning of the code that values are coming from database.

Here is what I have tried earlier: If the list of `VendorStores` is empty (blank), take one action. Else take another action. I was getting an error when `VendorStores` had more than one value (comma separated) and it was being compared to blank. So now I am trying to count the values and use that count to make a decision. But I am getting same issue. When `VendorStores` is blank, the `for` loop still thinks it has 2 values - 1) `",="` 2) `""`. Not sure why this is the case.

```
:: Intention of the script is as follows:
:: If VendorStores list is blank, take one action
:: If VendorStores list has values, take another action

@echo off
:: Set values for VendorStores
:: set vendorstores=123,234,345
:: Set VendorStores to blank
set vendorstores=
echo list = "%vendorstores%"
:: Remove any blank spaces from VendorStores
set vendorstores=%vendorstores: =%
set /a c=0
echo c=%c%
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%a in ("%vendorstores:,=" "%") do (
    if [%%a] NEQ [] (
        set /a c=c + 1
        echo VendorStore is %%a
    )
    echo c=!c!
)
echo c=!c!
if [!c!] EQU [0] (
    echo c is equal to Zero
) else (
    echo c is greater than Zero
)
echo c=!c!
endlocal
```

Comment: is it php or bush, add tags please?

Comment: It is batch file.

Comment: batch file - is not programming language or script. If you specify tag it would be more useful to filter your question depends on expert area.

Comment: Added Batch-file tag. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wrong result is from the **FOR** command line:

```
for %%a in ("%vendorstores:,=" "%") do (
```

With inserting above this command line a line with `echo on` and after closing parenthesis of **FOR** a line with `@echo off` it can be easily seen why it fails.

The right command line would be:

```
for %%a in (%vendorstores%) do (
```

But using this **FOR** loop is not good in case of environment variable `vendorstores` is not defined at all.

Here is a simplified example for batch file with name `Test.bat`:

```
@echo off
set "VendorStores=%~1"
if not defined VendorStores  goto EmptyList
set "VendorStores=%VendorStores: =%"
if not defined VendorStores  goto EmptyList
if "%VendorStores:,=%" == "" goto EmptyList
echo List is: %VendorStores%
goto :EOF

:EmptyList
echo The list is empty.
```

This batch file can be executed from within a command prompt window as follows:

```
Test.bat
Test.bat ,,,,
Test.bat ", , , ,"
Test.bat " 123, 234, 345 "
Test.bat "376,983,305,253"
```

The output on those 5 batch file executions is 5 times the expected output.

Comment: Mofi, Thanks a ton! What I was missing was "if not defined VendorStores". After removing the spaces from the delimited string, I added this statement before performing removal of commas. So here is what I did.

Answer (score 0):

```
:: Intention of the script is as follows:
:: If VendorStores list is blank, take one action
:: If VendorStores list has values, take another action

@echo off
:: Set values for VendorStores
:: set vendorstores=123,234,345
:: Set VendorStores to blank
set vendorstores=
echo list = "%vendorstores%"
:: Remove any blank spaces from VendorStores
set vendorstores=%vendorstores: =%

::::If there is any value in StoreCSV, then remove any comma delimiters from it as the "if" statement does not like commas
if defined vendorstores (
set "vendorstores=%vendorstores:,=%"
)

SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

if [%vendorstores%] EQU [] (
    echo VendorStores is blank
) else (
    echo VendorStores has one or more values
)

endlocal
```

Comment: It is not advisable to use `if [%vendorstores%] EQU []`. `[` and `]` have no special meaning. They are just two characters which need to be compared also on comparing the two strings left and right of operator `EQU`. Better is the usage of `if "%vendorstores%" EQU ""`. The double quotes are also included in string comparison done by __IF__ command. But within double quoted arguments command line operators like `&`, `|`, `<` or `>` are interpreted as literal characters and not as operators. This makes often an important difference.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "VendorStores="
For /F "EOL=, Delims=, " %%A In ("%~1") Do Set "VendorStores=%%A"
If Not Defined VendorStores (Echo VendorStores is blank
) Else Echo VendorStores has one or more values
```